# How to disable resize in firefox when using window.showmodeldilog

Tags: javascript, firefox

i am using `window.showmodeldialog` for opening a new firefox browser window, i want to disable re-sizing the newly opened window. In `window.open` i gave `resizable="no"` its working fine. I want to make it work for `window.showmodeldialog`

Comment: You say it's working fine, did you fix it yourself or are you still encountering a problem?

Comment: @David please read the question again

Comment: Firefox has a very cheeky thing about it where it allows many things to be user-changeable, even text boxes (If you have Firefox now, start a comment and look at the text box, it is realizable but it shouldn't be as you can make it over-sized and off the page, although in other browsers this isn't allowed. It's all about the browser itself and Firefox likes to be in control. There should be a way but you will need to look on firefox's page for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vReturnValue = object.showModalDialog(sURL [, vArguments] [, sFeatures])
```

**showModalDialog** [sFeatures]:

resizable:{ yes | no | 1 | 0 | on | off }

Specifies whether the dialog window has fixed dimensions. The default is no.
check more details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

or

http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-showmodaldialog-4-0-5-.aspx

In many posts, I read it will not support all browsers:

> It's working fine for IE. But whenever we use other browsers like
>   Opera, Mozilla or Netscape the popup never appears. Because
>   window.showModalDialog works for IE only.

Comment: That's because Firefox only implemented it relatively recently. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog for Mozilla's documentation. For me the dialogs are non-resizable by default, not sure what the op's problem is.